# how to make iOS simulator pick up real location of MAC

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

Sometimes I need to demo some apps that are location based. I like using my laptop and want to use if for the demo. I know I can change the location of simulator to not point to California, but is there a way to have cllocationmanager pickup actual location of the laptop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a matter of having GPS.

You need to look at the iOS Simulator as a virtual machine within osx. Like every virtual machine it has limited capabilities.
So in the current version it's simply not possible - sorry.

To change locations for the debugger, take a look at location debugger:
http://socialbit.de/location-debugger
(Note that I haven't tested this app)

Comment: "It's not a matter of GPS or not GPS" That a double negative dude. Just sayin ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Dont think mac has GPS , like iphone/ipad. 
What you could do is harcode the location to ur desired location.